# Where clause with multi AND & OR conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a table `agenda` in which the admin can make a reservation for him self or for someone else (another user). If the admin make the reservation for him self in `agenda.user_id` will be stored the `id` of admin.

In case that admin make a reservation for another person (another user) in `agenda.user_id` will be stored the `id` of the user for which the reservation will be made. The `id` of the admin will be stored in another column `agenda.booked_user`.

All the reservations are stored on `agenda_users` table also. `agenda_users` has this columns: `id`,`agenda_id`, `user_id`. The `agenda_users.user_id` it refers to `agenda.user_id`.

I want to retrieve all the reservations made by the admin which has made reservations for himself and for other users also.

I did a query with some AND & OR:

```
SELECT agenda.* 
FROM agenda,agenda_users 
WHERE agenda_users.agenda_id=agenda.id 
AND (agenda_users.user_id=$user_id 
AND agenda_users.user_id=agenda.user_id) 
OR (agenda_users.user_id=agenda.user_id 
AND agenda.booked_user=agenda.$user_id) 
AND checkout IS NULL 
AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(date_end, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) ORDER BY type ASC,date_start ASC
```

Cannot figure out the right solution to 'grab' all the reservations the admin has made for him self and other users.

Comment: It would already help if you use `JOIN` syntax, rather than antiquated comma separated joins

Comment: Due to the large number of unanswered questions popped up in the comments of answers, I voted to close the question with 'Needs more Detail or Clarity' reason.

Comment: Yeah I see what you trying to do but anyway @Luuk got the right answer!

Comment: I am not trying to do anything, there were and still are too many unanswered questions. You want a copy-paste ready answer, I did not provide it to you on purpose, but the main problem in your question is solved by it. UNION ALL and OR in WHERE are usually synonymous. You still don't need the join in the accepted answer. Luuk's answer solves your problem, I am fine with it, just this question won't help anybody else in the community and that is a pity.

Comment: There is a lot you need to explain. Please tell us exactly which columns belong in which table and what the three user IDs mean precisely. Why does the agenda table have two different users itself and then there are even child records in the agenda_users table, but you say all these child records must refer to the very same user. This really doesn't seem to make much sense. Please show sample data for the two tables along with the expected result.

Comment: And, no, it is very unlikely that Luuk's query is what you really need. See my comment below it.

Comment: That you are using a join syntax that was out of date already when MySQL came into existence is a weird thing, too. Who taught you to use a syntax made redundant almost thirty years ago??? Better quit that teacher, book or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solving the [old-style-joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) will leave you with this SQL:

```
SELECT agenda.* 
FROM agenda
INNER JOIN agenda_users ON agenda_users.user_id=agenda.user_id AND agenda_users.agenda_id=agenda.id
WHERE 
  (agenda_users.user_id=$user_id) OR (agenda.booked_user=agenda.$user_id) 
  AND checkout IS NULL 
  AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(date_end, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) ORDER BY type ASC,date_start ASC;
```

This SQL is almost human-readable (and understandable).

EDIT: Added extra `()` because AND has higher precedence than OR.

```
SELECT agenda.* 
FROM agenda
INNER JOIN agenda_users ON agenda_users.user_id=agenda.user_id AND agenda_users.agenda_id=agenda.id
WHERE 
  ((agenda_users.user_id=$user_id) OR (agenda.booked_user=agenda.$user_id)) 
  AND checkout IS NULL 
  AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(date_end, INTERVAL 6 HOUR) ORDER BY type ASC,date_start ASC;
```

Comment: This looks wrong. `AND` has precedence over `OR`. This means you have ` WHERE agenda_users.user_id = $user_id OR (agenda.booked_user = agenda.$user_id AND checkout IS NULL  AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(date_end, INTERVAL 6 HOUR))`.

Comment: The query is the same as the one from OP.   But you are right there is probably a need to add some `()` . (I will do an edit)

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment. So I am posting this as an answer and may adjust it, once you clarify doubts about the data model.

There is a parent table `agenda` and it has a child table `agenda_users`. So one agenda has several users. But the `agenda` table itself has two users, too. One is the person who made the reservation, but rather than using one column for that user, you are using sometimes one column and sometimes the other. You say that when an admin makes a reservation for another user, the admin gets stored in the column `booked_user`, although it's obviously not the booked user, but the booking user. I wonder whether you have understood the data model yourself, because the explanation sounds just wrong.

Then, an `agenda` should typically be identified by its `id` (hence the name), so the `agenda_users` should be linked via its `agenda_id` only. Are you sure that the `user_id` of the two tables must match, too? That would mean an `agenda.id` is unique only in combination with a `user_id`? It is possible, but doesn't seem likely.

Your query has some issues, too.

- `agenda.$user_id` is probably supposed to mean `$user_id` only?
- The parentheses are probably wrong, too, as `AND` has precedence over `OR`, so the `checkout` and `date_end` criteria will only work for the part after `OR`.
- Then you are missing qualifiers. This doesn't make the query wrong, but makes it more difficult to read. What table do `checkout` and `date_end` belong to? I assume it's the `agenda` table and will write my query accordingly, because you mentioned the columns of the `agenda_users` table and these two columns were not among them.

You want to select data from `agenda`. So, do so; don't join another table. If you have criteria based on the other table, then use `IN` or `EXISTS` for the lookup. In your case, though, - but I can only guess here - it seems you don't need the `agenda_users` table at all.

```
SELECT * 
FROM agenda
WHERE (user_id = $user_id OR booked_user = $user_id)
AND checkout IS NULL 
AND NOW() < DATE_ADD(date_end, INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
ORDER BY type, date_start;
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. You are right at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is cleaner in my opinion to use `UNION` instead of a very complex where conditions.

Note that you know the user_id you are filtering for, therefore you don't need to join.

```
/* The ones for admin created by the user */
SELECT
agenda.*
FROM
agenda A
WHERE
A.user_id = $user_id

UNION ALL

/* the ones where the admin created it, but not for itself */
SELECT
agenda.*
FROM
agenda A
WHERE
A.booked_user_id = $user_id
AND A.user_id <> $user_id
```

Don't forget to add the rest of the where conditions to both subqueries of the union

Comment: I think that  maybe it is  needed to distinguish admin from non admins even though it is not mentioned in the question `I want to retrieve all the reservations made by the admin which has made reservations for himself and for other users also`

Comment: @ErgestBasha There is no such thing in the query either. `agenda_user` is used only to filter by `agenda_users.user_id=$user_id `

Comment: Maybe it is confusing and with data templates would be much easier to understand. This part is confusing to me `If the admin make the reservation for him self in agenda.user_id will be stored the id of admin.
In case that admin make a reservation for another person (another user) in agenda.user_id will be stored the id of the user for which the reservation will be made. The id of the admin will be stored in another column agenda.booked_user.`

Comment: @ErgestBasha Assuming only admins can create entries for other users, the second query will result in 0 records for non-admin users, unless the user was once an admin, but is not now. For that there is no requirement defined and would be a different question. In its current state, the question is simply to list all reservations created by and for the specified user. Otherwise it is a different question, thus either the edit would be vandalism or the current question should be closed with 'requires more detail' reason.

Comment: Only the admin can make the reservation.

Comment: It's not working or it's just me who don't know to implement your query

Comment: Define 'does not work'. Also please define your exact requirements clearly. Maybe add some sample data and expected result to the question